# Antlr: Decision can match with multiple alternatives (starting with an illegal token?)

Tags: java, antlr

I have a grammar in Antlr to parse the format of a file I save. I broke the grammar down to the part that is not working and I hope someone can clarify. Here is the grammar:

```
grammar OptFile;

parseFile returns [java.util.List<java.util.List<java.util.List<String>>> list] :
{ list = new java.util.ArrayList<List<List<String>>>(); }
vc=VARIABLESCAPTION v=variables oc=OBJECTIVECAPTION o=objective
{ list.add($v.list); list.add($o.list); }
;

variables returns [java.util.List<java.util.List<String>> list] : 
{ list = new java.util.ArrayList<List<String>>(); }
(v=variable { list.add($v.list); } )*
;

variable returns [java.util.List<String> list] : 
{ list = new java.util.ArrayList<String>(); }
n=characters ';' t=characters ';' lb=characters ';' ub=characters ';' 
{ list = new java.util.ArrayList(); list.add($n.string); list.add($t.string); list.add($lb.string); list.add($ub.string); }
;

objective returns [java.util.List<String> list] :
{ list = new java.util.ArrayList<String>(); }
t=characters ';' { list.add($t.string); }
( 
      'PIECEWISE;' pw=piecewisefunction { list.add($pw.string); }
    | 'REGULAR;' rf=characters ';' { list.add($rf.string); } 
);  

piecewisefunction returns [String string] :
( characters ';' characters ';' characters ';' characters ';' )* 
{ string = getText(); }
;   

characters returns [String string] :
( ~(';') )* { string = getText(); }
;

VARIABLESCAPTION : '--Variables:--' ;

OBJECTIVECAPTION : '--ObjectiveFunction:--' ;
```

A valid input shall look like one this:

```
--Variables--x;INTEGER;0;INFTY;y;CONTINUOUS;-12;13;--ObjectiveFunction--MAX;13x^27+SIN(y);
```

or like this

```
--Variables--x;INTEGER;12;20;--ObjectiveFunction--MAX;x;12;x;16;0,5x;16;x;20;
```

After '--Variables--' can be arbitrary many variables with four fields each, after '--ObjectiveFunction--' is one field and then either one more field or arbitrary many "packs" of four fields.

Apparently, when compiling with Antlr, I get the following error:

```
warning(200): OptFile.g:26:37:
Decision can match input such as "OBJECTIVECAPTION {OBJECTIVECAPTION..VARIABLESCAPTION, 'PIECEWISE;'..'REGULAR;'} ';' 'PIECEWISE;' {OBJECTIVECAPTION..VARIABLESCAPTION, 'PIECEWISE;'..'REGULAR;'} ';' {OBJECTIVECAPTION..VARIABLESCAPTION, 'PIECEWISE;'..'REGULAR;'} ';' {OBJECTIVECAPTION..VARIABLESCAPTION, 'PIECEWISE;'..'REGULAR;'} ';' OBJECTIVECAPTION ';' 'PIECEWISE;'" using multiple alternatives: 1,2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
```

My questions now are:

1. How can the input even start with OBJECTIVECAPTION, as far as I understand, the input for my grammar has to start with VARIABLESCAPTION.
2. What do I need to change, to get this grammar running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message may be a bit cryptic, but the problem is in production `variables`, it defines zero-or-more occurrences of `variable`. A variable can begin with the input shown in the error message, but `variables` can also be followed by the same input, that occurs in its invocation environment. Thus there is a problem deciding between continuation in `variables` (alternative 1) and completing it (alternative 2).

So the error message does not refer to the complete input, but to an input fragment that is going to be matched by `variables`. The line number shown should point you to the production that presents the problem.

For fixing it, you could introduce a delimiter for the list, such that it becomes clear when to stop collecting more occurrences of `variable`, e.g.

```
parseFile : VARIABLESCAPTION variables '.' OBJECTIVECAPTION objective ;
```

---

EDIT by Asker:

I tried the approach and it works great, but only if the dot that is used as seperation symbol is added to the list of characters that have to be ignored, i.e. the code line for `characters` has to be modified:

```
characters : ( ~(';' | '.') )*;
```

After that, it works just fine.